# Reading characters from binary file

Tags: c++, file, binary

I'm trying to write number of X characters (of value from -128 to 127 ) to a binary file, then I want to read all of them but after reading one of them the rest of the characters are not being read from the file.

This is my code which writes and then reads the file:

```cpp
file.write(&x,sizeof(char));    
file.read(&y,sizeof(char));
```

Why it is not reading all of the characters?

Comment: How are you making sure you wrote all characters to your file? Is the file size after writing as large as you expect?

Comment: It is, im writing chars in 2 loops. All of them are written in the binary file the problem is as I said when reading one of them the rest wont be read

Comment: Then please show that code as well. There are no loops in your example code!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the size of the read and write to be equal to a single `char`. So you write 1 char and then read 1 char.

Comment: i just wanted to show my way of writing and saving, Im writing lot more than 1 char. Those 2 functions are inside loops

Comment: @kepcius then maybe you should show all of your code and not the code that you say is correct. You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34116272/edit) your question to include **all** neccessary information

Answer (score 0):

I was copying my code here and Ive found the problem ( I didnt open the file in abinary mode). Now its working as planned